# AWS lambda fails to call Facebook SDK

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, aws-lambda, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am setting up a AMS lambda to call the facebook sdk internally but unfortunately I am not able to get any response from facebook SDK.

Please find the below code :-

```
const listCampaign = async (event, context) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    await validateAuthToken(event.headers.Authorization, event.headers.accountId);
    console.log("account are",account)
    return  await account.getCampaigns([
        Campaign.Fields.account_id,
        Campaign.Fields.adlabels,
        Campaign.Fields.bid_strategy,
        Campaign.Fields.boosted_object_id,
        Campaign.Fields.brand_lift_studies,
        Campaign.Fields.budget_rebalance_flag,
        Campaign.Fields.budget_remaining,
        Campaign.Fields.buying_type,
        Campaign.Fields.can_create_brand_lift_study,

    ])
        .then((campaign) => {
            console.log("first check 3",campaign) // No response from facebook SDK and after 30 sec it get end point time out
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause could be that the security group is not configured for outside connections. If that is not the case and the lambda function is deployed in a VPC, please do check that the VPC subnets have NAt and Internet gateway permissions.